# Python RegEx match results are too minimal, please advise

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm stumped as to why this Python regex doesn't give me the expected results. In the example below, I am expecting the output to be "/w:document/w:body/w:sectPr" but the actual result (Python v3.2) is "/w:sectPr". I have simplified my problem for the following example.

```
import re

path = "/w:document/w:body/w:sectPr/w:footerReference"
rxSetting = re.compile('(/\w+:[^/]+){3}')   # top-three
matchSetting = rxSetting.match(path)
setting = matchSetting.group(1)
print(setting)
```

When I check it with regexpal, it matches what I wanted.  Do I need to do something
specific in Python to make this work?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this :

```
rxSetting = re.compile('((?:/\w+:[^/]+){3})')
```

If you want to capture (group) the first three you will need the parenthesis around the whole regex.

Comment: Thanks!  Now I feel like I missed the obvious solution.

Comment: No problem!  Please give this answer a check if you feel it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole match, you can also just use `.group(0)` or `.group()`